# Entering a start date and an end date and inserting the dates in between into db

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a query to run in php that would let you insert all dates in between two dates?

For example, entering 03/20/2012 and 03/20/2013 and populating mysql with all the dates in between the two?

I was making a ticketing system for an airline and they have 13 flights daily from 20+ locations and inserting them manually was getting tedious.

I wanted to insert the dates as well as the values for each day

EG.

```
 FROM                TO              Date_From              Date_To
     Dar Es Salaam      Zanzibar         03/20/2012             03/21/2012
     Dar Es Salaam      Zanzibar         03/21/2012             03/22/2012
```

**Note**

I do not want to GENERATE this list (the questions I've researched only answered how to generate a list) I want to POPULATE a MySQL DB

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did i ask a question that's invariably stupid so no one is bothering to answer, or did I stump the stackoverflow community O_o.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this function to generate an array of dates

```
function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'd/m/Y' ) {

    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime( $first );
    $last = strtotime( $last );

    while( $current <= $last ) {

        $dates[] = date( $format, $current );
        $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
    }

    return $dates;
}

$dateRange = dateRange("03/20/2012", "03/20/2013);
```

and then iterato over the array to insert the data

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (from, to, date_from, date_to) VALUES (:from, :to, :datefrom, :dateto)");
$stmt->bindParam(':from', "Dar Es Salaam");
$stmt->bindParam(':to', "zanzibar");
$stmt->bindParam(':from', $datefrom);
$stmt->bindParam(':to', $dateto);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dateRange); $i++){
   $datefrom  = strototime($dateRange[$i]);
   $dateto  = strototime($dateRange[$i+1]);
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: This one actually might seem like its going to work. Ill test it out and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to populate a DB is to generate a list of SQL insert queries.

So if you can GENERATE a list of queries that do something like `insert into table (... , date_from, date_to, ... ) values ( ..., val1, val2, ...)` you can then run these queries and POPULATE the table.

Comment: Theyre not in the db yet. Instead of manually inserting them one by one using the insert into table clause, I wanted to know if there was a query that would populate the db with the data in between the two dates

Answer (score 0):

```
$int_date_from = strtotime($str_date_from); // Will be used often
$int_days = (strtotime($str_date_to) - $int_date_from); // Calculate difference in seconds
$int_days /= floor(60 * 60 * 24); // Seconds to days

$arr_values = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $int_days; $i++) {
    $str_new_date_from = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+{$i} Days", $int_date_from));
    $str_new_date_to = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+'.($i + 1).' Days', $int_date_from));

    $arr_values[] = "('{$str_from}', '{$str_to}', '{$str_new_date_from}', '{$str_date_to}')";
}

$str_values = implode(', ', $arr_values);

mysql_query("
INSERT INTO table
VALUES {$str_values}
");
```